# Show that the second derivative $\Gamma''(x)$ is positive when $x>0$

Tags: derivatives, complex-numbers, gamma-function

Let $\Gamma(x)=\int_0^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$.

I know that the first derivative is positive, since $\Gamma(x)$ is increasing when $x>0$, but I don't know how to show that the second derivative is positive without calculating it, something which we have not yet learned to do.
Plotting out $x!$ shows that $\Gamma$ is concave up, and has a positive second derivative, but I don't know how to formulate a formal proof.

Would it suffice to say $\Gamma(x+2)-\Gamma(x+1)>\Gamma(x+1)-\Gamma(x)$, $\forall x>0$, and $\Gamma$ is increasing at an increasing rate?

Comment: Which definition of $\Gamma$?

Comment: The integral representation is pretty useful here if you can use it.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I can't say $\frac{dx}{dt}\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{dt}t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt$, right?

Comment: @MattG not without justification. In this case it happens to be true because of the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @MattG Yes - if you are careful enough

Comment: "Would it suffice to say ...?" - No. One can easily come up with non-convex functions having this property, e.g. $\Gamma(x):=\sin 2\pi x+x^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define $$\Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty t^{x-1} e^{-t}\; dt$$ then 
$$\Gamma''(x) = \int_0^\infty t^{x-1} \ln(t)^2 e^{-t}\; dt > 0$$

BTW, it's **not** true that $\Gamma'(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$.  $\Gamma$ has a minimum at approximately  $1.4616321449683623413$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\log\Gamma(x)$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}^+$ due to the [Bohr-Mollerup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem).

So $\Gamma(x)$ is a convex function on $\mathbb{R}^+$ as the exponential of a convex function, and $\Gamma''(x)\geq 0$.